# Database first with EF6 SqlAnywhere provider in VS2017

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sqlanywhere

Having already followed the advice in the SAP website documentation and installed the developer edition of SQLAnywhere 17, and also having manually run the installer for VS integration that is provided by this installation I still could not see any providers other than the MSSQL ones while creating an EF6 model in Visual Studio 2017.

I found this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.EF6/17.0.7.3399

Does anyone know where to find documentation on how to use it? Nuget provides no links to documentation and does not list a repo.

I installed the package without incident and it appears in project references but it does not appear in the provider list when I try to create an EF model.

A request to the package author provoked this response:

> Hi Peter,
>
> For information and documentation go to:
>   https://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/
>
> or with SyBase
>   http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01776.1604/doc/html/san1357754863708.html
>
> Kind Regards, Erwin Bakels

While I appreciate the prompt response, the documentation link leads to information about doing another thing with a different version -- it's for code-first with EF4.3 while the library is for EF6 and I need database-first. To be fair to Erwin, I didn't explicitly tell him I wanted database-first, but it's still not a usable answer.

Further research suggests that changes in VS2017 prevent the installer from registering the provider correctly. This implies that until such time as SAP updates the installer to suit VS2017 there is no possibility of designer support for EF with SQL Anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed with SAP support, that Sql Anywhere ADO.NET integration with Visual Studio is not supported in VS2017. You will have to use VS2015 or earlier.

Comment: Since then I have figured out how to shell dbisql from Visual Studio code, which gives me a decent editor that can capture results (the Sybase tool is crappy), and I am using the ODBC driver with Dapper and hand crafted classes to receive query results. This approach is also compatible with dotnet Core.

Answer (score 0):

[SAP DocCommentXchange](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sqla170/en/html/3bd3aed06c5f1014b1588c778b156f8d.html)

I suggest you download the SQL Anywhere, developer edition.  You will get all the files necessary to use EF.

Comment: What is the most recent version of Visual Studio with which you have tried this?

Comment: Your solution doesn't help due to changes in VS2017. I did mention this requirement but it was buried in the text. I have put it in the title so it's more obvious.