# Visual Studio 2017 - SQL Anywhere 12 data provider

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, sqlanywhere

I can't seem to get VS2017 to find my SA12 data source as a valid data provider. I've installed SA12 build 4155.

Using VS2012 I am able to find it, but not in VS2017. Could anyone help me? Opening 'other' sources only lists several .Net Framework Data Providers, but not Sql Anywhere.

[image]

Comment: I do not believe it is possible with VS 2017 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50522334/database-first-with-ef6-sqlanywhere-provider-in-vs2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted SAP support and they confirm that the ADO.NET provider is not supported for VS2017. Currently they have no plan to support it either, which might give some clues about the future of Sql Anywhere.

VS2015 is the latest version that suppports ADO.NET integration with Visual Studio.